Angular 7 - ERROR in node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.directive.d.ts(15,16): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'DataTables'
ERROR in node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.directive.d.ts(15,16): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'DataTables'.
node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.directive.d.ts(27,25): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'DataTables'.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(29,13): error TS2456: Type alias 'RowSelector' circularly references itself.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(35,5): error TS2315: Type 'RowSelector' is not generic.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(38,13): error TS2456: Type alias 'ColumnSelector' circularly references itself.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(50,13): error TS2456: Type alias 'CellSelector' circularly references itself.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(1356,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(1437,19): error TS2315: Type 'RowSelector' is not generic.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(1440,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(1823,19): error TS2315: Type 'RowSelector' is not generic.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(1834,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.
node_modules/datatables.net/types/types.d.ts(1917,19): error TS2315: Type 'RowSelector' is not generic.

I'm getting this error in my angular project I just upgraded from 6 to 7, has anyone had something similar?
I updated my angular and now this error appears.

https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1248
